# Changing the number size on a 3d plot for the z axis in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, mplot3d

I know this seems like a really simple question, but does anyone know how to change the sizes of the numbers for the z axis in a 3d plot like the one below? I know how to do it for the x axis and y axis where I would use

```
  plt.xticks(size=20)
  plt.yticks(size=20)
```

But when I use `plt.zticks(size=20)` it doesn't seem to work.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can change the properties of the third axis using this command

```
ax.zaxis.set_tick_params(labelsize=20)
```